# Can a `readOnly` property be part of a PUT/POST in OpenAPI?

Tags: json, openapi, readonly

If a property is defined as `readOnly` in OpenAPI, is it reasonable to say it is valid to be part of the request but not mutable?

In the potential use case, an `id` is flagged as `readOnly` and **MAY** be part of the payload as part of a sub-collection to the resource. If the `id` is included the resource of that sub-collection is referenced.

```json
{
  "a", "b",
  "lorems": [
    {
      // he's talking about ME! *blush*
      "id": "abc123",
      "name": "A new name for the existing object"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is the language in the OpenAPI spec perhaps just fuzzy enough to be okay with this?

Answer (score 0):

> readOnly properties are included in responses but not in requests

Source: [Read-Only and Write-Only Properties](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#readonly-writeonly)

My understanding of this sentence is: You should **NOT** include the property in request.

---

I think it's a bit clearer in the `writeOnly` section where they say:

> writeOnly properties may be sent in requests but not in responses

The way I understand it is "writeOnly should not be used in response". Using the same logic, I understand the `readOnly` sentence as "readOnly should not be used in request".